# Help identify: multi-player but single character role playing game

Tags: identify-this-game

*(This is a question which overlaps with role-playing games, you will see why when you read it; however this seemed to fit it slightly better.)*

My friend mentioned he had a role-playing game which plays like the following: Every player controls one single, shared character. The players take turns to give the character commands on their turn, sometimes rolling dice to decide certain factors e.g. the existence of a certain facility in a town. Each player has a goal which they are attempting to make the character achieve while foiling the other players' goals - however no players are aware of the other players' goals. Each player is also provided with a number of "points" which are used similarly to gambling chips. The person who is prepared to pay the most points takes the next go, but loses the points they played.

My friend is cannot remember the name of the game, but has created a homemade rendition. He is not even sure if it ever existed outside of his mind. My question is, does this game exist, and if so, what is it called?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to [Role-playing Games Stack Exchange](http://rpg.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you're thinking of [Everyone is John](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/18124/everyone-john)?

> The main concept is that every player but one plays a voice in "John's" head. All of these voices are trying to get John to do something that they like.

Other similarities:

- Shared character: Everyone is John, obviously.
- Hidden goals: EiJ gives each "voice" three hidden goals of varying feasibility, worth points based on their difficulty.
- Points: Voices bid to get control of John at various points in the game

Comment: If someone has a better source than 1d4chan I'd be ecstatic if you could add it in comment or edit, but as Everyone is John is a pretty small RPG mainly distributed online that was the source that I knew it from.

Comment: https://rpggeek.com/rpg/18124/everyone-john

Comment: Take this game, and play a session inspired by the book [John Dies at the End](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1857440.John_Dies_at_the_End).  I think that could be highly entertaining, and thematically appropriate on both counts.